# rspec test if method is called

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I can't figure out how to write a test that will work, that also doesn't run anything in my script in the CL. When @counter is 9, it is supposed to trigger #tie_game? but it does not work. @counter is initialized to 0 and is incremented by one every time a player puts an X or an O on the game board. How can I test that once @counter is 9 that it calls tie_game? and that when it is less than 9 it will not?

```
def initialize(player1, player2)
    @player1 = player1
    @player2 = player2
    @rows = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

    @wins = [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], 
        [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],
        [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]

    @selected_numbers = []
    @counter = 0
end

def increment_counter
    @counter += 1

    if @counter == 9
        tie_game?
    end
end

def tie_game?
    puts "The game was a tie. Nicely played #{@player1} & #{@player2}!"
    play_again  
end
```

I tried this: Can you explain why it does not work though?

```
describe "increment_counter" do
    context "counter equals 9" do
        it "calls tie_game?" do
            game.instance_variable_set(:@counter, 9)
            allow(game).to receive(:increment_counter)
            #expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).with("The game was a tie. Nicely played #{@player1} & #{@player2}!")
            expect(game).to receive(:tie_game?)
        end
    end
    context "counter is less than 9" do
        it "does not call tie_game?" do
            game.instance_variable_set(:@counter, 4)
            game.increment_counter
            expect(game).not_to receive(:tie_game?)  
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I saw your edit after I posted my answer.  The reason it's not working for you is that you're never actually calling your code after setting the expectations.  When testing whether messages are sent and received, you have to invert the expectation/run order.

Comment: okay awesome. Thanks so much for your help, that definitely makes more sense

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RSpec Mocks do this for you.

```
describe TicTacToe do
  let(:game) { TicTacToe.new }

  context "after fewer than 9 moves" do
    it "does not call tie_game?" do
      expect(game).not_to receive(:tie_game?)
      8.times { game.increment_counter }
    end
  end

  context "after 9 moves" do
    it "calls tie_game?" do
      expect(game).to receive(:tie_game?)
      9.times { game.increment_counter }
    end
  end
end
```

See https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/basics/expecting-messages for more details.

As a side note, tie_game? probably shouldn't have a question mark after it.  tie_game? suggests that it's checking to see if the game is tied.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I could delete lots of code because of this.

Comment: Side note, that you can't use `have_received` without doubles. You have to test `receive` like in this example.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. My approach is monkey-patching the class, redefine the method `tie_game?` that makes some side effect which can be detected by the test.

Since I don't see your class name, let's just call it `Foo`.

First, create a module, say `TrackMethods`

```
module TrackMethods
  # A global variable that stores how many times a method is called.
  $method_calls = Hash.new(0)

  def self.[](*method_names)
    Module.new do
      method_names.each do |name|
        define_method name do |*args, &block|
          $method_calls[name] += 1
          super(*args, &block)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in *spec_helper.rb*

```
Foo.prepend TrackMethods[:tie_game?]
```

After that, in your tests, you can

```
expect($method_calls[:tie_game?]).to be > 0
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I just made an edit to my OP